# UUCP on old Xenix with serial line no modem

Tags: serial-port

A little question about UUCP on Xenix or other old Unix.
I have set up UUCP as follow:

```
Devices
Direct tty2a - 9600 direct
Systems
xenix2 Any Direct tty2a 9600 12345 in:--in: user word: password
```

There are two systems connected directly with serial ports (tty2a of xenix1 to tty2a of xenix2).

CU works fine but UUCP does not, why?

Comment: This doesn't look like a BNU UUCP configuration file. Can you get the version from UUCP (maybe from the man page)?

Comment: cu doesn't use the chat script portion of the Systems line, and that's likely the portion that needs to be adjusted to get uucico to work. You can run `uucico -r1 -sxenix2 -x5` to get some debugging output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was permissions errors. I had to set correctly `/usr/uucp/lib/` permissions.